# Crystal Report exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010, crystal-reports-10

I have developed a project with Crystal Reports 10 and developed a setup which works fine generating the pdf file but when I install this application in any other machine and try to run pdf generation than I get this exception:

See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'
at WindowsApplication1.frmPaySlip.ShowReportSalaryStatement(DataSet ds, String toadd, String rep)
at WindowsApplication1.frmPaySlip.pdfgenerator(String rep, String toadd)
at WindowsApplication1.frmPaySlip.btnOK_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)

at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

I have tried almost every possibility I found in the net but couldn't get sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

I Sorted out with the issue. The reference of crystal report was referring to the other version of dll so it was working fine in machine and throwing error for other machine. I cleared all the reference and rerefered all the dll `s of crystal report and rebuild the setup its working fine now